# Multi upload com variados formatos php e mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7.1

Gostaria de fazer um multi upload com variados formatos de img, estou pesquisando como faz usando php 7.1, entendi mais o menos a logica do negocio.
só que nao estou conseguindo reproduzir.

Alguem poderia me dar uma mao ou link com uma referencia correta da aplicação de multi upload com variados formatos de arquivo

```html
== index.php
<body>
   <h3>Photo Gallery</h3>

   <form action="add-album.php" method="post">
        <label>Add New Album</label>
        <input type="text" name="album_name">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_album" value="Add">
</form>
<?php 

 if(isset($_GET['add_album_action'])){
  if ($_GET['add_album_action'] == "sucessfull") { ?>
  <br>New Album created <br><br>
 
  <?php }
 }
 ?>
 <?php

$albums = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_albums");
while ($album_data = $albums->fetch_assoc()) {
 $photos = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = ".$album_data['album_id']."");?> 

<b>#<?php echo $album_data['album_id'] ?></b> <a href="view-album.php?album_id=<?php echo $album_data['album_id'] ?>"><?php echo $album_data['album_name'] ?></a> (<?php echo $photos->num_rows; ?>)<br><br>
<?php }
 ?>
</body>

upload_photo.php

<?php
include 'connection.php';



$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
if ($_FILES['photo']['name'] != null) {


    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "images/". $_FILES['photo']['name']);

$photo_link = "images/". $_FILES['photo']['name'];
 
$upload_photo = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO gallery_photos (album_id, photo_link) VALUES ($album_id, '$photo_link')");
if ($upload_photo) {


header("Location: view-album.php?album_id=$album_id&amp;upload_action=success");
} else {

echo $mysqli->error;
}

} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>;
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_GET['album_id'])) {
$album_id = $_GET['album_id'];
$get_album = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_albums WHERE album_id = $album_id");
$album_data = $get_album->fetch_assoc();
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo $album_data['album_name'] ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$photo_count = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $album_id");
?>
<a href="index.php">Home</a> | <?php echo $album_data['album_name'] ?> (<?php echo $photo_count->num_rows; ?>)<br><br>
<form method="post" action="upload_photo.php?album_id=<?php echo $album_id ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Add photo to this album:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="photo" /> 

<input type="submit" name="upload_photo" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['upload_action'])) {
if ($_GET['upload_action'] == "success") { ?>
<br><br>Photo successfully added to this album<br><br>
<?php }
}
?>



<?php
$photos = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_photos WHERE album_id = $album_id");
while($photo_data = $photos->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<img src="<?php echo $photo_data['photo_link'] ?>" width="200px" height="200px" />
<?php }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primeiro sugiro que aprenda upload simples de um só arquivo. Um problema no que postou começa desde o básico no HTML. Na tag `<form>` falta defnir o `enctype="multipart/form-data"` e um elemento `input type="file"`. Por hora, o que pede está amplo. Há muitas coisas desde o upload e validação de tipos de arquivos. Pergunte uma coisa só.

Comment: fico grato! vou adicionar e continuar pesquisando sobre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em um dos meus projetos precisei realizar uma tratativa sementante ao proposto na pergunta. Fiz alguns ajustes para que melhor se adapte ao seu cenário.

```
$files = $_FILES;
$config = [
    'type_file_allowed' => ['jpeg', 'png', 'jpg'],
    'file_error_message' => [
        0 => 'Não houve erro e o upload foi bem sucedido.',
        1 => 'O arquivo enviado excede o limite definido.',
        2 => 'O arquivo excede o limite definido em MAX_FILE_SIZE no formulário HTML.',
        3 => 'O upload do arquivo foi feito parcialmente.',
        4 => 'Nenhum arquivo foi anexado',
        6 => 'Pasta temporária estar ausente.',
        7 => 'Falha ao escrever o arquivo em disco.',
        8 => 'Uma extensão do PHP interrompeu o upload do arquivo.'
    ]
];

$upload_files = images($files, $config);
salve($upload_files);

function images($files, $config) {
    $images = [];
    $files = structureUploadFile($files);    

    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {    

        $extension = pathinfo($file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array($extension, $config['type_file_allowed'])) {
            throw new Exception('File extension '. $extension .' not allowed');
        }

        array_push($images,
            [
                'file' => [
                    'name' => strtolower($file['name']),
                    'path' => $file['tmp_name'],
                    'attach' => ($file['error'] == 4) ? false : true,
                    'file_message' => 
                       $config['file_error_message'][$file['error']]
                ]
            ]
        );
    }

    return $images;
}

function structureUploadFile($files) {
/*
Função responsável por transformar os atributos do file em chaves
Antes do método structureUploadFile o file vem agrupado assim:
array(1) {
  ["file"]=>
      array(5) {
        ["name"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=> string(13) "alert-git.png"
              [1]=> string(15) "arquivo git.png"
            }
        ["type"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=> string(9) "image/png"
              [1]=> string(9) "image/png"
            }
        ["tmp_name"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpdDHYVq"
              [1]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpGVjQUt"
            }
        ["error"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=> int(0)
              [1]=> int(0)
            }
        ["size"]=>
            array(2) {
              [0]=> int(73549)
              [1]=> int(76928)
            }
      }
}

//Depois do método
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(5)
    {
        ["name"]=> string(13) "alert-git.png"
        ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpdDHYVq"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(73549)
    }
  [1]=> array(5)
    {
        ["name"]=> string(15) "arquivo git.png"
        ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
        ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpGVjQUt"
        ["error"]=> int(0)
        ["size"]=> int(76928)
     }
}

 */

    $file_identification = array_keys($files['file']['name']);

    $attribute = [];
    foreach ($files['file'] as $key_params => $params) {
        array_push($attribute, $key_params);
    }

    $data = [];
    foreach ($file_identification as $id) {
        $values = array_column($files['file'], $id);
        array_push($data, array_combine($attribute, $values));
    }

    return array_combine($file_identification, $data);
}

function salve($images) {
    foreach ($images['file'] as $key => $images) {
        if ($images['attach']) {
            //executa select
        }
    }
}
```

Você não comentou nada de como está pegando os dados, mas caso precise trabalhar de forma assíncrona, ou seja, sem atualizar a página, você pode utilizar alguns *plugins javascript*, por exemplo:

- [Jquery-upload-file](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php)
- [HTML5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/](https://dcrazed.com/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/)
- [FileAPI](https://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/)

Comment: Djama e como eu faria para processar cada array e colocar as multiplas no banco de dados direto? eu talvez teria que colocar um foreach e dar um insert eu tenho a logica mais o menos

Comment: Sim. O código é apenas para montar a estrutura para facilitar na hora de salvar. Sendo assim, você terá que fazer um `foreach` para percorrer o `array`, conforme o `function salve($images)`.