# Passando $_FILES em uma função de cadastro

Tags: php, imagem, arquivo

Bom, estou pensando em uma forma de cadastrar itens em um banco de dados, porém, pensei:

> "e se o item tiver uma imagem ?"

Então escrevi um script para enviar essa imagem, porém, não sei se é correto ou não passar o `$_FILES` como parâmetro de uma função que será chamada em outro script. Sendo assim, poderiam me ajudar dizendo se há algum erro, ou se há uma outra forma de realizar o envio da imagem ?

```
function adicionaCarta($cardName, $cardQuantity, $cardEditionID, $cardTypeID, $cardAttibuteID, $cardMonsterTypeID, $cardLRL, $cardATK, $cardDEF, $cardDesc, $cardStatusID, $query, $conexao){

    if(isset($_FILES['imagem-card']['name']) && $_FILES['imagem-card']['error'] == 0){
        $arquivo_tmp = $_FILES['imagem-card']['tmp_name'];
        $nomeCard = $_FILES['imagem-card']['name'];
        // Pega a extensão
        $extensao = pathinfo($nomeCard, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Converte a extensão para minúsculo
        $extensao = strtolower($extensao);
        // Somente imagens, .jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png
        if(strstr('.jpg;.jpeg;.gif;.png', $extensao)){
            // Cria um nome único para esta imagem
            // Evita que duplique as imagens no servidor.
            // Evita nomes com acentos, espaços e caracteres não alfanuméricos
            $novoNomeCard = uniqid(time()) . '.' . $extensao;
            // Concatena a pasta com o nome
            $destino = '../img/cards/' . $novoNomeCard;
            // tenta mover o arquivo para o destino
            if(@move_uploaded_file($arquivo_tmp, $destino)){
                mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
            }else{
                echo 'Erro ao salvar o arquivo. Aparentemente você não tem permissão de escrita.<br />';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Você poderá enviar apenas arquivos "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png"<br />';
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Você não enviou nenhum arquivo!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua dúvida é como gerenciar o salvamento da imagem e relacionar as informações da carta salva em banco?

Comment: @DNick, minha dúvida é se, ao executar a função, devo ou não passar o $_Files como parâmetro, ou se apenas dentro da função ele já roda sem problemas, e caso precise passá-lo como parâmetro, como o faço ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `$_FILES` nada mais que um *array*. E conforme a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php) do PHP, ele diz:

> Um array associativo de items enviado através do script atual pelo
>   método HTTP POST. A estrutura deste array é detalhada na seção Uploads
>   com o método POST.

Em questão de definição, o que é o `$_FILES`? Com base na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

A variável **global** `$_FILES` conterá toda a informação do arquivo enviado. E ela assume o nome do arquivo enviado no input, por exemplo `name="file"`, mas isso não impede que seja qualquer nome.

Uma variável global ou [superglobais](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.superglobals.php)

> são variáveis nativas que estão sempre disponíveis em todos escopos. Ao contrário das variáveis locais que declaramos que tem o comportamento inverso, ou seja, está disponível apenas no escopo que ela foi criada.

A variável `$_FILES` é apenas uma das variáveis globais, há também:

- $GLOBALS
- $_SERVER
- $_GET
- $_POST
- $_FILES
- $_COOKIE
- $_SESSION
- $_REQUEST
- $_ENV

O fato da variável ser global e um array, nada impede de você passar como parâmetro de um método. O que é aconselhável é fazer uma verificação se ela existe e se foi preenchida corretamente no `<form>`, por exemplo:

```
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    metodoQualquer($_FILES);
}
```

Você também pode atribuir a uma variável para que seu código fique mais legível

```
if (isset($_FILES)) {
    $imagem = $_FILES;
    //ou
    $arquivo = $_FILES;
    //ou
    $pdf = $_FILES;
    metodoQualquer($pdf);
}
```

Então sobre suas dúvidas:

**Devo ou não passar o $_Files como parâmetro, ou se apenas dentro da função ele já roda sem problemas?** R: Por ser uma variável global você não é obrigado a passá-la como parâmetro para acessá-la dentro de um método. Mas procure validar se a variável foi definida `if (isset($_FILES)){}`, além de que, deve-se tomar cuidado para não sobrescrevê⁻la em outro ponto do arquivo.

Recentemente postei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220116/multi-upload-com-variados-formatos-php-e-mysql/220191#220191) sobre como manipular o $_FILES com múltiplos arquivos. Neste exemplo real que fiz eu manipulo e passo-o por parâmetros no método.

Comment: mas como passo ela por parâmetros ?

Comment: atualizei e coloquei um exemplo na prática no final da resposta para você dar uma olhada

Comment: é necessário passar o $_FILES como parâmetro para usá-lo na função ?

Comment: Por ser uma variável global você não é obrigado a passá-la como parâmetro para acessá-la dentro de um método. Mas procure validar se a variável foi definida `if (isset($_FILES)){}`, além de que, deve-se tomar cuidado para não sobrescrevê⁻la em outro ponto do arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

Tem algumas coisas que não aconselhava na sua função como o uso de @ para 'encobrir', 
passar a coneção e query por parametro, 
usar função strstr, 
aconselhava um array para verificares as extensões, aqui vai um exemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $j = 0; //Começamos pelo indice 0

    $caminho = "uploads/"; //Definir o caminho para salvar o arquivo
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['name']); $i++) { // loop a cada elemento selecionado

        $extensoesValidas = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png"); //extensoes que são permitidas
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i])); //achar a extensao
        $extensaoFicheiro = end($ext); //guardar as extensões

        $caminho = $caminho.md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1]; //setar o caminho com o novo nome da imagem 
        $j += 1; //incrementamos o nº de uploads  

        if (($_FILES['file']['size'][$i] < 100000) //aproximadamente 100kb
            && in_array($extensaoFicheiro, $extensoesValidas)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i], $caminho)) {
                echo $j.
                ') Imagem enviada com sucesso';
            } else { //se a imagem nao foi movida
                echo $j.') Aconteçeu um erro por favor tente novamente.';
            }
        } else { //se o tipo ou tamanho nao é conrespondente 
            echo $j.') extensão ou tamanho invalido, tente novamente.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mas no caso, devo passar o $_FILES como parâmetro na função ou dentro da própria função apenas, sem parâmetro ele já funciona ?

Comment: se sim, como passo o $_Files como parametro?