# php - upload multi imagens para mesmo campo

Tags: php

Boa Noite,

Tenho uma dúvida e uma questão...

Eu quero fazer upload de múltiplas imagens, mas na minha base de dados tenho la 2 campos:

```
 Imagem_1 e Imagem_2.
```

Mas não sei como separo as imagens, visto ser tudo do mesmo array $_POST['imagens']

Alguma dica?

Comment: Essa resposta pode te ajudar: [Como tratar muilt upload da forma certa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220116/multi-upload-com-variados-formatos-php-e-mysql/220191)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que a questão não é o código em si, por isso vou focar somente na lógica.

Quando tu for percorrer a variável das imagens com o `foreach`, tu compara a posição delas com a variavel `$key`. Então no `if` que compara se `$key == 0`, vai o código que faz a inserção no banco e move para a pasta a primeira imagem, e no `else`, vai fazer o mesmo com a segunda imagem

```
foreach($_FILES['imagem'] as $key => $imagem) {
  if($key == 0) {
    // Codigo que vai salvar na coluna imagem_1 e mover para a pasta
  } else {
    // Codigo que vai salvar na coluna imagem_2 e mover para a pasta
  }
}
```

Comment: ok mas exemplo... EU tenho dado para inserir tambem, nao vou inserir-los 2x... como faço para inserir os dados juntamente com essas imagens?

Comment: Posso usar tipo... $_FILES['imagem'][0], e $_FILES['imagem'][1] ?

Comment: Faz dois inserts, um para as imagens e outro para os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um input com o atributo name como um array:

```
<form action='' method='post'>
    <input name='imgs[]' type='file' multiple>
</form>
```

E no PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST["imgs"]);
```

O resultado vai ser algo assim:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "img1.png" [1]=> string(8) "img2.png" }
```

Então é só fazer um loop e converter as imagens para o tipo blob, mover para uma pasta ou apenas salvar o nome do arquivo